# Setting up Programm-o locally

Tags: apache, xampp, server

After reading the installation guide for program-o http://blog.program-o.com/documentation-v2/installation/ I was wondering how I would go about doing step 2 locally and installing it without hosting an online server?

Comment: You put the files in a suitable directory on your local web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your code in **htdocs** directory (inside xampp instalation directory).

Then You will be able to execute your code by typing 'localhost' in your browser.

Or if you want to use other domain instead of localhost, You have to edit your hosts file.

In Windows7 hosts file is located in:

> %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc

My hosts file for example:

```
127.0.0.1       domain.com
```

I can access my code by typing for example 'domain.com' instead of 'localhost'

Comment: 'localhost' indicates to htdocs dir. Put index.html with some text and try to execute it.